# Non-async function not being found in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

If the function below, called getData, is defined as an async function then it is being found later when called in the body. However if only 'async' is removed while defining it, then we get the error "ReferenceError: getData is not defined". Why is this happening? How does a function being defined as async or not affect when it is registered in the global scope?

Define a function in the head tag as:

```
<script>
    async function getData() {
        const x =[] 
        const y =[]
        const response=await fetch('data.csv');
        
        console.log('response revieved');
        const data = await response.text();
        console.log(data);

        split=data.split('\n').slice(1);

        split.forEach(row => {
            columns=row.split(',')
            x.push(columns[0])
            y.push(columns[1])
        });
        return{x,y}

    
}
</script>
```

Then later this is called in body tag as

```
const data = getData()
```

Comment: presumably because after you remove the `async` you will have a syntax error of using `await` inside a non-`async` function, so `getData` won't be defined. And because you have 2 separate script tags an error in the first doesn't stop the second trying to run.

Comment: If you put another `function abc () {}` after that one in the same script tag, even `abc` will suddenly be undefined if you remove `async` from `getData`. That's because without the `async` your whole script tag is not valid JavaScript anymore and can't be executed (instead you should see a syntax error in your browser console).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How does a function being defined as `async` or not affect when it is registered in the global scope?

It doesn't, but removing `async` from **that** function causes a syntax error on the `await`. You should be seeing that in your browser console and/or build tools output. You can't have `await` inside a non-`async` function. So since it causes a syntax error, the function doesn't get created, nor does anything else in that script.

Example:

```js
function getData() {
        const x =[] 
        const y =[]
        const response=await fetch('data.csv');
        
        console.log('response revieved');
        const data = await response.text();
        console.log(data);

        split=data.split('\n').slice(1);

        split.forEach(row => {
            columns=row.split(',')
            x.push(columns[0])
            y.push(columns[1])
        });
        return{x,y}

    
}
```

If you want to make that a non-`async` function, you have to convert the `await` to promise callbacks, like this (see also some other notes):

```
function getData() {
    return fetch("data.csv")
    .then(response => {
        // *** Side note: This check was missing
        // More in my blog post: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
        }
        return response.text();
    })
    .then(data => {
        const x = [];
        const y = [];

        // *** Side note: Was missing `const` (or `let`)
        const split = data.split('\n').slice(1);

        // *** Side note: This could be a `for-of` loop, which might be clearer
        split.forEach(row => {
            // *** Side note: Was missing `const` (or `let`)
            const columns = row.split(',');
            x.push(columns[0]);
            y.push(columns[1]);
        });
        return {x, y}
    });
}
```

But note that it still does most of its work asynchronously. It has to, because of the nature of `fetch`.

I'd leave it as an `async` function. They're supported in all modern environments.

Answer (score -1):

Because await need an async function, async transform the function to a promise and then you could use await
take a look at this to learn more: https://learnjsx.com/category/2/posts/es6-promise